# Checking if a UDP message is sent in C

Tags: c, udp

I want to check why a program is not receiving UDP messages. A client program is sending 4 integers every time sample. I have a server program that is using "recvfrom()" to get the UDP messages on a port but the program does not seem to be receiving the messages on the port number and is stuck in the "recvfrom" function. I was wondering if there are debugging techniques I can use to debug this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to check the return values of all your function calls to verify that they are completing successfully (as opposed to indicating an error).  Consider running a network protocol analyzer such as wireshark on each end.

Comment: Make sure its not being blocked by your firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities, common case could be,

1. Firewall on your machine or in transit, for example, your another endpoint is behind a firewall that disallow UDP inbound traffic from this address.
2. Routing, make sure the ping works
3. Your code bug, make sure loopback address works

To debug, you could install Wireshark to inspect specific interface's traffic.